# Structural induction in Haskell

Tags: haskell, induction

Is the following a definition of structural induction?

```
foldr f a (xs::ys) = foldr f (foldr f a ys) xs
```

Can someone give me an example of structural induction in Haskell?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You did not specify it, but I will assume `::` means list concatention and
use `++`, since that is the operator used in Haskell.
To prove this, we will perform induction on `xs`. First, we show that the
statement holds for the base case (i.e. `xs = []`)

```
foldr f a (xs ++ ys) 
{- By definition of xs -}
= foldr f a ([] ++ ys)
{- By definition of ++ -}
= foldr f a ys
```

and

```
foldr f (foldr f a ys) xs
{- By definition of xs -}
= foldr f (foldr f a ys) []
{- By definition of foldr -}
= foldr f a ys
```

Now, we assume that the induction hypothesis `foldr f a (xs ++ ys) = foldr
f (foldr f a ys) xs` holds for `xs` and show that it will hold for the list
`x:xs` as well.

```
foldr f a (x:xs ++ ys)
{- By definition of ++ -}
= foldr f a (x:(xs ++ ys))
{- By definition of foldr -}
= x `f` foldr f a (xs ++ ys)
         ^------------------ call this k1
= x `f` k1
```

and

```
foldr f (foldr f a ys) (x:xs)
{- By definition of foldr -}
= x `f` foldr f (foldr f a ys) xs
         ^----------------------- call this k2
= x `f` k2
```

Now, by our induction hypothesis, we know that `k1` and `k2` are equal,
therefore

```
x `f` k1 =  x `f` k2
```

Thus proving our hypothesis.