# Filter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, filter, functional-programming, filtering

I have the following problem.

Prove that for all finite lists xs of some type and predicates p and q on that type:

```
filter p (filter q xs) = filter q ( filter p xs)
```

Do I need some sample xs lists for solving this? Or how must this problem be solved?
Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: using induction. For example check [Structural induction in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14960598/1308058)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, providing some `xs` samples is not what this exercise requires.

This exercise is asking you to *prove* for all possible values of `p,q,xs`, the the equation holds. Note that there are infinitely many possible values for `p,q,xs`, so it is unfeasible to brute force all the possible cases: a general mathematical proof must be provided, leveraging some logical principle.

Just to make a comparison, suppose you are asked to prove that `2*x+x = 3*x` in an exercise. The expected solution is not "well, it holds on `x=4` and `x=10`", neglecting all the other (infinitely many) values for `x`. A reasonable solution could be: "I have `x=1*x`, and so by the distributive law 
`2*x+x = 2*x + 1*x = (2+1)*x = 3*x`", which works for *all* `x`.

In this kind of exercises, often one must proceed by induction on something. Here, `xs` looks as a good candidate for induction. So, to prove the equation true for all `xs`, it is necessary to prove

1. the equation holds for `xs=[]`
2. if the equation holds for `xs=ys` (`ys` being arbitrary), then it must hold for `xs=y:ys` (`y` being an arbitrary value)

If you prove 1. and 2. then you are done.

Just one extra hint: since `y` is arbitrary, you do not know if it satisfies predicates `p` and/or `q`. You can however check all the possible four cases there: both `p,q` hold, only `p`, only `q`, neither.